# Use separate input as parameter to Lambda layer in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Say I have layer in my neural network with an output that looks like this:

```
output = (None, 5, 25)
```

I want to write a Lambda function that can take an average of these 25-dimensional tensors, but slice the items based off an index value that would be passed as a separate input.

```
index_input = (5,)
```

So I figured it could maybe be done with a Lambda like this:

```
def TargetAverage(x, nt):
    new = x[:, 0:nt[1]]
    new = backend.mean(new, 1)     
    return new
```

And then pass the output of the input tensor as an argument:

```
    new_output = Lambda(TargetAverage, arguments={'nt': index_input})(output)
```

And then expected output would be the average of those 5 vectors up to the point of the index value:

```
 (None, 25)
```

But it seems like this would only feed it the symbolic tensor, not the actual value.

Any idea how this could be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an example input and the expected output?

Comment: "pass the output of the input tensor"? what does that mean? Yes, a numerical and concrete example would help us to better understand it.